# VueJS Axios POST returns NULL when passing variable through pages

Tags: javascript, php, vuejs2, axios

I've been trying hours to understand this and re-check StackOverflow's answer. Tried copy pasting too, didn't work.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    jobtype_select: '',
    jobtype_list: [{
        id_JobType: 'JTY0001',
        name_JobType: 'Survey'
      },
      {
        id_JobType: 'JTY0002',
        name_JobType: 'Research'
      },
      {
        id_JobType: 'JTY0003',
        name_JobType: 'Maintenance'
      }
    ],
    woFormABCD: '',
    totallyRandom: 'Hello Heiayo'
  },

  methods: {
    recordTESTWo() {
      var form = new FormData();
      form.append('test', this.totallyRandom);
      axios.post('action.php',
          form
        )
        .then(function(response) {
          alert('Success!');
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <form method="post" action="action.php" @submit.capture='recordTESTWo'>
    <div class="">
      <label for="jobtype_id" class="control-label required"><strong>Choose Job Type</strong></label>
      <div v-for='jobtype in jobtype_list'>
        <label class="">
                            <input  type="radio" 
                                    id= 'jobtype_id'
                                    v-model= 'jobtype_select'
                                    :value="jobtype.id_JobType"
                                    name='jobtype_select' 
                                    > 
                            {{jobtype.name_JobType}}
                        </label>
      </div>
      <p> This is : {{jobtype_select}}</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

What I wanted to do was to try to pass `totallyRandom` value to the next page. Which is `action.php`.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    //$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), TRUE);
    printf("This is GET: \r\n");
    var_dump($_GET);
    printf("This is POST: \n");
    var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

**What I expect to see,**
the variable of `totallyRandom` being passed to `action.php` so I can use it on `action.php` page.

**What I see,**
Also, when I go to action.php, and do var_dump it returns NULL. The radio button passed, but that's not using Axios. More details can be asked,

[image: Picture]

Comment: Can you try using submit.prevent

Comment: I just noticed that it produces an error log, question updated with info of .capture and .prevent errror log. So does this mean it's Vue's fault instead? Not Axios'?

Comment: Two things wrong. First, it's [`methods`, not `method`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods). Second, when you use `FormData`, axios will post a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded request body so your PHP should use `$_POST['test']` and not `php://input`. **Voting to close as a typo**

Comment: @Phil Ok, so I tried yours, changed 'method' to methods', changed url to 'action.php' then alert('Success') is launched. I've seen data on console, but in my action.php when I var_dump("$_POST"); Now it says I have an array which is zero instead.

Comment: Wanted to edit, and upload a picture, unfortunately StackOverflow won't let me, and I don't have any idea why, but let that aside. I uploaded it here https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tsPx.png

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking now but I suggest you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52993918/edit) to update the code and explain what you expect to see vs what you actually see. FYI, if you open `http://110.0.4.16/myplaindashboard/action.php` directly in your browser, that will be a GET request and `$_POST` will be empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `<form>` is submitting normally. That's why you see the `jobtype_select` POST parameter instead of `test`.

This can be easily solved by using the `.prevent` [event modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) instead of `.capture`

```
<form @submit.prevent="recordTESTWo" ...
```

---

FYI, `.capture` is for...

> an event targeting an inner element is handled here before being handled by that element

This relates to the *`useCapture`* parameter of [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters) whereas `.prevent` calls `preventDefault()` on the event.